# Мой кот(,) хоть и не любит рыбу, ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

`Мой кот(,) хоть и не любит рыбу, ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны:

***Мой кот хоть и не любит рыбу, ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской***;

***Мой кот, хоть и не любит рыбу, ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской***.

---

**Зависит от решения автора.**

Если автор решит отнести словосочетание *мой кот* к придаточной части, он **не будет ставить запятую**, а в таком случае поменять местами нельзя, тут фиксированная позиция для придаточного:

***Мой кот хоть и не любит рЫбу, ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской***.

Во втором варианте, если автор решит отнести *мой кот* к главной, он **поставит запятую**; в таком случае поменять местами **можно**:

***Мой кОт, хоть и не лЮбит рыбу, ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской***;

***Мой кот ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской, хоть и не любит рыбу***.

Здесь придаточное можно перемещать, но перед главным поставить **нельзя**.

---

Вывод: запятая зависит от решения автора.

Answer (score 2):

1. Запятая ставится в **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОМ** порядке, если это придаточное предложение, и решение однозначное (без вариантов) при таком порядке слов:

*Мой кот, / **хоть и не любит рыбу**, / ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской.*

Это СПП, придаточное уступительное находится в середине главного предложения (**интерпозиция!**), союз ***ХОТЯ И***.

2. Но другой вариант все-таки **возможен**, если его правильно **объяснить:**

*Мой кот **хоть и** не любит рЫбу, ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской.*

А как **ОБЪЯСНИТЬ**? Берем словарь и смотрим значние слова "хотя/хоть". Это не только союз, **но и частица: II. частица.** 1. Употр. для усиления того слова, к которому относится. Тогда у нас две частицы ***ХОТЬ + И*** со **свободной** позицией.

**Примечание**

**Не так просто** подобрать контекст для такого предложения, например:

**Какие бывают коты (диалог)**

*— Все коты любят рыбу, а мой нет. В рыбе же много витаминов. Чем его кормить!..*

*— Мой кот, хоть и не любит рыбу, ест очень много брокколи и брюссельской.* Там тоже есть витамины.